# Compare current date & last month date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

This is my query. I want system date with subtracted month but it gives no record.

```
select REGION, 
       CURR_DATE 
  from DCC 
 where CURR_DATE<(select DateAdd(MM, -1, GetDate()))
```

This query gives me all records less then or equal system date.

So please give me correct solution for = `sysdate - one month`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query, [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function

```
select REGION,CURR_DATE from DCC where CURR_DATE < (SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

You can Get last one month record using between

```
select REGION,CURR_DATE from DCC where CURR_DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW();
```

Comment: Why use `DATE_ADD` with a minus value instead of `DATE_SUB`? No reason to go `10 + (-1)` when you could do `10 - 1`.

Comment: you can do this number of way, in this time this function come in my mind that's why i put that query first.